# Indentation in listing with Python

Tags: listings, indentation, python

I am inserting snippets of `python` code into a `latex` document using the [`listing`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listing) package. When writing code comments in the code snippet the indentation level is not maintained.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
breakatwhitespace=false,         
breaklines=true,                 
captionpos=b,                    
keepspaces=true,                 
numbers=left,                    
numbersep=5pt,                  
showspaces=false,                
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,                  
tabsize=2
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
def blahblahblah:
''' some very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong code description'''
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Using `breaklines=true` breaks the long code to fit on the page but it does not maintain the current indentation.

**Question:** Is there a way to get listing to recognise and maintain the current indentation state within listings?